# InfluxDB local server ( Unable to write gathered points )

Tags: influxdb

Hi After installing an InfluxDB V 2.3.0 on a Windows 10. At the run time, I obtain a recurring error message :

```
PS C:\Program Files\Influxdb\serveur> ./influxd
2022-08-11T15:29:51.960087Z     info    Welcome to InfluxDB     {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "version": "v2.3.0+SNAPSHOT.090f681737", "commit": "090f681737", "build_date": "2022-06-16T19:34:12Z"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.965507Z     info    Resources opened        {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "bolt", "path": "C:\\Users\\dsii\\.influxdbv2\\influxd.bolt"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.965507Z     info    Resources opened        {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "sqlite", "path": "C:\\Users\\dsii\\.influxdbv2\\influxd.sqlite"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.973780Z     info    Checking InfluxDB metadata for prior version.   {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "bolt_path": "C:\\Users\\dsii\\.influxdbv2\\influxd.bolt"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.973780Z     info    Using data dir  {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "path": "C:\\Users\\dsii\\.influxdbv2\\engine\\data"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.975035Z     info    Compaction settings     {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "max_concurrent_compactions": 6, "throughput_bytes_per_second": 50331648, "throughput_bytes_per_second_burst": 50331648}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.975035Z     info    Open store (start)      {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "start"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.975035Z     info    Open store (end)        {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "end", "op_elapsed": "0.000ms"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.975035Z     info    Starting retention policy enforcement service   {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "retention", "check_interval": "30m"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.975035Z     info    Starting precreation service    {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "shard-precreation", "check_interval": "10m", "advance_period": "30m"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.976033Z     info    Starting query controller       {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "storage-reads", "concurrency_quota": 1024, "initial_memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "max_memory_bytes": 0, "queue_size": 1024}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.980021Z     info    Configuring InfluxQL statement executor (zeros indicate unlimited).     {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "max_select_point": 0, "max_select_series": 0, "max_select_buckets": 0}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.987130Z     info    Starting        {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "telemetry", "interval": "8h"}
2022-08-11T15:29:51.988147Z     info    Listening       {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "tcp-listener", "transport": "http", "addr": ":8086", "port": 8086}

2022-08-11T15:30:01.998674Z     error   Unable to write gathered points {"log_id": "0cFOGPM0000", "service": "scraper", "scraper-name": "new target", "error": "database not found: 2b596978fb5a7411"}  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Look like your scrapper cause this error. You can check it under `Load Data > Scrappers` in InfluxDB UI. This may happen when you create a scrapper for a bucket then you delete that bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty simple: *"database not found: 2b596978fb5a7411"}*

Check the following

- does the database exists?
- user permission, can it write to that database/bucket? (InfluxDB 2 uses buckets)

If you come from InfluxDB v1 some additional setup is needed to be compatible with the old [Database-RetentionPolicy mapping](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/influxql/#map-unmapped-buckets).